# Laravel Blade return output of a "route name", not the URI

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have this footer inside a blade template. This footer should be **displaying a variable dynamically** inside the said template.

```
template.blade.php

<html>
    <body>
        @include('templates.usermenu.usermenu')
        @include("templates.navigation.navigation")
        @yield('header')
        @yield('content')

        {{ route('footer-links') }} <--this is the footer. this only outputs the "URI"
    </body>
</html>
```

here is the output of the code above

[image: output for the code above]

Here is the `footer.blade.php` with a variable that should be displayed:

```
footer.blade.php

{{-- buttons --}}
@foreach ($footerLinksRecord as $record)                
    <div class="clearfix">
        <a class="poppins-medium text-md button-white text-left float-left clickable" href="{{ $record->link }}">{{ $record->name }}
        </a>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

The `footer.blade.php` needs to output a variable coming from its `FooterLinksController@index` (the `template.blade.php` **does not have** any controller managing it).

Here is the route for the `footer.blade.php` and the `home.index` (`home.index` calls the `template.blade.php` inside its code):

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home.index');
})->name('home');

// Footer Links Index
Route::get('/footer', [FooterLinksController::class, 'index'])->name('footer-links');
```

Here is the `FooterLinksController@index`:

```
public function index()
    {
        $footerLinksRecord = FooterLinks::all();

        return $footerLinksRecord;
    }
```

What should happen is that the `footer.blade.php` **should output the data of its route** when called, not the URI.

How should this be approached?

**edit** removed `@include`. I'm looking at the wrong code.

Comment: `route` just gives you the URL. It sounds somewhat preposterous to use a controller with URL and all that for a footer. You want to `include` that footer similar to what you're doing with the menu and navigation!

Comment: @deceze I've decided to use something like this in the `templates.blade.php`. `@include('footer.index', ['footerLinksRecord' => $footerLinksRecord])`. this only throw an error since the `home.blade.php` does not have any controller managing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a View Composer to handle the data for the `footer` view. You can include the footer where needed without worrying about the data needed for it.

You can create a new Service Provider or add to the `boot` method of an existing one:

```
public function boot()
{
    ...
    View::composer('footer', FooterComposer::class);
}
```

You can use a class with a `compose` method to handle composing the view instead of a Controller:

```
class FooterComposer
{
    ...
    public function compose($view)
    {
        $view->with('footerLinksRecord', FooterLinks::all());
    }
}
```

In the layout, `template.blade.php`, you only have to 'include' the footer:

```
@include('footer')
```

You also have the option of making a Blade component for the footer instead.

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Views - View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers)

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Blade - Components](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#components)

Comment: do I need to create my own service provider?

Comment: you could create a new service provider if you would like ... the `@include('footer')` is the only part in a blade file (the layout, to include the footer)

Comment: ok so let me clarify this for a bit. I need to create my own service provider (let's call it "ViewServiceProvider) and attach the code starting from `public function boot()` until the `public function compose($view)`, right?

Comment: thanks for editing your answer. so let me clarify this:
- `public function boot()` code is inside a newly registered service provider (if I choose to register a new one)
- if `boot()` is inside `{insertNameHere}ServiceProvider`, the `class FooterComposer` would also be inside the `{insertNameHere}ServiceProvider`?

Comment: I would like to accept that your answer is the right answer, but some things need to be clarified first so that future readers of this question would follow exactly what to do if they choose to follow your answer. **Your answer works btw but I need some tinkering before I make it work** (thanks tho)